# AudioBoo date format with javascript or jquery

Tags: jquery, datetime, date-formatting

I have pulled data from the `AudioBoo` API. Each recoding has a time that it was recorded/submitted but it is in this format...

`2012-04-11T09:57:38Z`

Is there any way that I can convert this to read something like

`11th April 2012`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use ***[datajs](http://www.datejs.com/)***. Here is the ***[doco](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation)*** and ***[format specifiers](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers)***.

```
var x = new Date('2012-04-11T09:57:38Z'),
    result = x.toString('ddS MMMM yyyy');

alert( result );
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VHCUJ/)**